# Redirect a subdomain to a different subdomain using host records

Tags: redirect, subdomain

I have two domains example.com and example2.com; the second domain is simply to catch a common misspelling of my name and I want to redirect everything on it to example.com.

I have a number of subdomains set up on example.com and I want to redirect urls at example2.com to the appropriate subdomain on example.com. I have seen solutions for this using htaccess but I do not want to create an actual site on a server for example2.com so I want to do it through host records.

Here is an example of what I have done so far on example2.com (I am using Namecheap):

| Type | Host | Value |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| URL Redirect Record | @ | https://example.com | Permanent (301) |
| URL Redirect Record | mysd | https://mysd.example.com | Permanent (301) |

The root domain redirect is working fine but subdomains are also redirecting to the root i.e. mysd.example2.com goes to example.com instead of mysd.example.com.

What do I need to change here?

Comment: Well, because you configured it to redirect to the root. Configure the desired subdomain instead.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - Sorry, I had it configured ok in Namecheap, I mistyped above and have now edited the original post.